# Logitech unifying receiver, Chrome plugin work on android?

Tags: keyboard, chrome-for-android, usb-drivers, mouse

I lost my antenna for my Logitech keyboard and mouse. I decided to buy a Logitech Unifying Receiver. But I can't find any drivers for it for Android except the [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/logitech-unifying-for-chr/agpmgihmmmfkbhckmciedmhincdggomo/reviews?hl=en).

I don't understand, is the driver running from Chrome (on android) or is it for Chrome OS only?

I have a Android 6.0 for my TV box.

To reiterate, can I install the driver in Android Chrome and pair my mouse and keyboard to my TV box that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I belive your keyboard and mouse are plug 'n' play so you don't need to install any driver on your device, just plug into it the Unifying reciever.

Comment: the mouse and keyboard are plug n play but I need to pair them with this receiver (all bough separately ). And for that I need the drivers.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I missed that information. But I think if you want to pair your keyboard and mouse with the new reciever you should use a computer due to the pairing procedure requires the [Logitech Unifying Software](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/unifying) but it's not available for Android.

Comment: That's true but there is a program for Chrome `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/logitech-unifying-for-chr/agpmgihmmmfkbhckmciedmhincdggomo/reviews?hl=en
`. And I'm wondering if that can solve my problem

Comment: Yeah, it's a program for Chrome Desktop not for Chrome Android. You can't use plugins from Chrome Store on Chrome Android.